# CakePHP not respecting foreignKey name

Tags: mysql, cakephp, foreign-keys, cakephp-2.0

I have an `articles` table with a column `tagging_id` that needs to reference the `id` column in a table called `tracking_categories` as a foreign key.

My `Article.php` file has the following:

```
class Article extends AppModel {
    public $controllerPath = 'articles';
    public $useTable = 'articles';

var $binds = array(
    'TrackingCategory' => array(
        'bindType' => 'belongsTo',
        'className' => 'TrackingCategory',
        'foreignKey' => 'tagging_id'
    ),
    'Channel' => array(
        'bindType' => 'belongsTo',
        'className' => 'Channel',
        'foreignKey' => 'channel_id'
    )
);
```

My `TrackingCategory.php` looks like this:

```
class TrackingCategory extends AppModel {

     public $useTable = 'tracking_categories';
```

I have the following in the `AppModel` which `Article.php` inherits:

```
function expects($binds, $reset = false) {
    if (func_num_args() > 2 || !is_bool($reset)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Did you mean to pass an 
array of binds?');
    }

    if (!is_array($binds)) {
        $binds = array($binds);
    }

    foreach ($binds as $bind) {

        if (isset($this->binds[$bind])) {
            $tmp = array($this->binds[$bind]['bindType'] => array($bind => $this->binds[$bind]));
            $this->bindModel($tmp, $reset);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:
`Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Article.tracking_category_id' in 'field list'`

It is still looking for the column named parsed via CakePHP's naming convention rather than the name that I explicitly set via the `foreignKey` value.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax should be:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'TrackingCategory' => array(
        'className' => 'TrackingCategory',
        'foreignKey' => 'tagging_id',
    )
);
```

For more information, see [CakePHP 2.x - Associations: Linking Models Together - belongsTo](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto).

Comment: The alternative syntax works fine for every other bind in that model just not for this new one.  This is an existing project for an organization.  I can't just go changing working syntax.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I edited the question to include Channel which is bound and is working properly.  The only difference is that channel_id does conform with CakePHP's naming convention.

Comment: Check other working models for something like `$this->bindModel($this->binds);` somewhere in the code. It could be called from within the constructor or the `beforeFind()` callback.

Comment: Yes, we have that and that's certainly how this alternative syntax is working but that shouldn't have any effect on Cake ignoring my foreign key name, right?

Comment: Ok, edited.  I don't have that function in `Article.php` but `Article.php` extends `AppModel` and it's in there.

Comment: I believe you are using a variation of [this code](https://github.com/ceeram/static_bakery/blob/master/src/articles/2006/12/Keeping-bindModel-and-unbindModel-out-of-your-Controllers.rst), wich later [evolved on to this](https://github.com/ceeram/static_bakery/blob/master/src/articles/2007/03/An-improvement-to-unbindModel-on-model-side.rst). Are you sure you are on CakePHP 2.x? Sounds more like 1.x to me. Anyway, `expects()` should be called with the second parameter set to false. Please make sure this is the case.